# What could be the reason my side-menu not collapsing while reducing the tab width or when checking view in Phone or tablet?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, handlebars.js, side-menu

This is my PC layout which can be seens as:
[image]

But while reducing the window width to check if its mobile friendly and responsive all the side menu `<ul>` get scaled up together. I want to hide them and introduce a menu button instead of that on which clicking the side-menu options should appear then only. Here is the screenshot for that:

[image]

The content looks fine as mobile friendly and responsive as below you can see it is aligned perfectly one after one the problem is with the side menu.
[image]

Here is my side-menu `HTML` code:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <header>
      <a href="/"><img src="/images/grumpy-removebg-preview-removebg-preview.png" width="50" height="25"> grumpytext</a>
    </header>
    <ul class="nav navbar-expand-md">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="zmdi zmdi-view-dashboard"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/profile">
          <i class="zmdi zmdi-view-dashboard"></i> Dashboard
        </a>
      </li>
      <li id="addtasks">
        <a href="/addtasks">
          <i class="zmdi zmdi-link"></i>➕ Add Task
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/status" id="status">
          <i class="zmdi zmdi-widgets"></i> Status
        </a>
      </li>
      <li  style="height : 120px">
        <a href="/download" id="download">
          <i class="zmdi zmdi-calendar"></i> Download
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="zmdi zmdi-calendar"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
      <a href="/storageClient">
        <i class="zmdi zmdi-info-outline"></i> Storage
      </a>
    </li>
      <li>
      <a href="/settingsClients">
        <i class="zmdi zmdi-info-outline"></i>⚙ Settings
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/logout">
        <i class="zmdi zmdi-info-outline"></i> Logout
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div style="font-size:12px">COPYRIGHT © 2018 - 21 · GRUMPYTEXT.COM,
         ALL RIGHTS RESERVED.</div>
      </a>
    </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Here is my `CSS` code:

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  #sidebar {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
  }
  #sidebar a {float: left;}
  content {margin-left: 0;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  #sidebar a {
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
  }
}
.fWyFhS {
    display: inline-flex;
    box-shadow: rgb(0, 135, 90) 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    animation: 0s ease 0s 1 normal none running none;
}

.form-signin {
  max-width: 330px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.form-article {
  max-width: 1000px;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}



#sidebar {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  left: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -250px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #2a2b3d;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#sidebar header {
  background-color: #2a2b3d;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 52px;
  text-align: center;
}

#sidebar header a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#sidebar header a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

#sidebar .nav{

}

#sidebar .nav a{
  background: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #455A64;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 16px 24px;
}

#sidebar .nav a:hover{
  background: none;
  color: #4660CC;
}

#sidebar .nav a i{
  margin-right: 16px;
}
```

Comment: you just want the reason or solution ?

Comment: I need a solution first.

Comment: your #sidebar css is causing the issue.if you are using bootstrap then use thier nav template